# How to check if variable is set and not NULL/Empty and save it for further use on the next page?

Tags: php

I've got an application which has an embedded IE6 browser. On opening it inside the application, it sends a `$_POST`  variable: `$_POST['VARIABLE']`.

What's the best way to check in the start of my script that if this variable isn't sent (security check to make sure it's opening only via the application) and save it  to use it on the next page?
I use sessions on my website since I store account `id`s, `email`, `password`, so I believe I can use it to save this variable too. Please let me know.

Comment: Sessions are the general way to save values from one page to the next. You should be able to use it for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if(!array_key_exists('VARIABLE',$_POST))
{
   //this variable is not set in post - proceed accordingly
}
else
{
  //value is sent from POST, lets put it in session if its not already there,
  //or if a previous POST value is still in session - lets update that
  if(!array_key_exists('VARIABLE',$_SESSION) || 
  $_SESSION['VARIABLE'] != $_POST['VARIABLE'])
  {
     $_SESSION['VARIABLE'] = $_POST['VARIABLE'];
  }
}

// ...in the rest of the code check $_SESSION['VARIABLE'] and act accordingly.
```

Comment: Thanks, also wanna know if I should actually sanitize the post variable when it's set to the session? => `  $_SESSION['VARIABLE'] = $_POST['VARIABLE'];` .. I am sure that my application cannot be altered to change the post variable but still is it better to do it to be 100% sure about it? let me know please?

Comment: @Monk25 - OF COURSE!!! Do not put anything user provided data in DB OR session OR anywhere else unless its sanitized. That is the rule of the thumb. Doesn't matter how secure you think your app is :)

Comment: Alright, thanks. Good to be sure about it. So, putting unsafe (non-sanitized) variable into the session string should be considered unsafe as well ?

Comment: What I usually do is - instead of using `$_POST['var']`, I get the value using a custom function I write like `$var = getPost('var')`. And in the `getPost()` I write code to get the value from POST and to sanitize it. That means the value in `$var` is now clean and safe. This way I do not have to care about sanitizing each variable or not based on how I use it - to put in session, to update DB, or just to delete after a few lines. All my variables are sanitized, period. I think that is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find this usefull, some tests I just did:

```
echo isset($nothing) ? 'y' : 'n'; // no
$something = '';
echo isset($something) ? 'y' : 'n'; // yes
unset($something);
echo isset($something) ? 'y' : 'n'; //no

echo NULL == NULL        ? 'y' : 'n'; // y
echo NULL == ''          ? 'y' : 'n'; // y
echo NULL === ''         ? 'y' : 'n'; // n
echo NULL == $nothing    ? 'y' : 'n'; // y
echo NULL === $nothing   ? 'y' : 'n'; // y
echo NULL === $nothing   ? 'y' : 'n'; // y
$something = 'asd';
echo NULL === $something ? 'y' : 'n'; // n
```